# how to make multi dimensional array with for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

```
FirstName = FirstName.value;
LastName = LastName.value;
Adress = Adress.value;
for(i=0 ;i<10;i++){
    contacts[i] = [];
    for(c=0;c<3;c++){
        contacts[i].push(FirstName);
        contacts[i].push(LastName);
        contacts[i].push(Adress);
    }
}
```

the code gives me the contacts array with 10 arrays and each array has the information repeated 3times

Comment: check out this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545641/javascript-multidimensional-array

Comment: @Erick How is it even closely related to this question?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the second `for` loop:

```
FirstName = FirstName.value;
LastName = LastName.value;
Adress = Adress.value;
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    contacts[i] = [];
    contacts[i].push(FirstName);
    contacts[i].push(LastName);
    contacts[i].push(Adress);
}
```

Or you can also use this way:

```
FirstName = FirstName.value;
LastName = LastName.value;
Adress = Adress.value;
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    contacts[i] = [FirstName, LastName, Adress];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure on the objective but I think you should be using objects to store your information instead of 2D arrays. 
([Jsfiddle that show 2d array and array with objects](https://jsfiddle.net/stevenkaspar/y7t75v9k/)). So instead of

```
var contacts = [
  ['John', 'Doe', '100 Main Street'],
  ['Jane','Smith','101 Main']
];
```

you would have

```
var contacts = [
  {
    first_name: 'John',
    last_name: 'Doe', 
    address: '100 Main Street'
  },
  {
    first_name: 'Jane',
    last_name: 'Smith', 
    address: '101 Main Street'
  }
];
```

Try this. It will push the form name and email onto the contacts

```
<form onsubmit='formSubmit(event);'>
  <label>name</label>
  <input id='name' value='John'/>
  <label>email</label>
  <input id='email' value='fake@test.com'/>
  <br/>
  <button>
  add name and email
  </button>
</form>

function formSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    contacts.push({
      name: document.getElementById('name').value,
      email: document.getElementById('email').value
    })
    console.log(contacts);
}
```

Comment: but how to make the script create an object each time the user fill the informations