# error on associative multidimensional array assignment in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I'm trying to use an associative multi-dimensional array in javascript, but there is something wrong in the code.

html

```
<p onclick="myFunction()">Test</p>
```

javascript

```
myFunction = function() {

  alert(1);

  obj['temp']['room'] = 1;

  alert(2);

}
```

The result is that only the first alert is fired.
What is wrong in the definition of the array?

Comment: Given that there are no associative arrays in JavaScript, there aren't any multidimensional ones either. You can nest objects, though.

Comment: Please learn [how to open the console in your browser](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525), and read what it says. It likely says something is undefined. In this case, `obj`.

Comment: See [How to open the JavaScript console in different browsers](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) and you'll find the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript multidimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545641/javascript-multidimensional-array)

Comment: -1 on my own question! :-( 
As you suggested, a simple console would have solved the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the variable and initialize it as [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer), then you can assign a value.

```
var obj = { temp: {} };
obj['temp']['room'] = 1;
```

Comment: Nina beat me to the punch :) Here's my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Currell/rczh2gtq/1/

Answer (score 1):

That term "associative array" is just an alias for an object treated in a way that "associates" to how arrays are used in code (like in your example). Your code expects this (so, make sure you have it before attempting to use it):

```
var obj = {
  temp = {
    room = 1
  }
};
```