# three-dimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var a = new Array();
var b  = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
for(i in b){a[i] = new Array(new Array());}
a[0][1][2] = Math.random();// error:VM205:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '2' of undefined(…)
```

How to use three-dimensional array in javascript?

i mean how to use it like java.
eg: `double a = new double[length][length][length];`

how to memorize memory in advance.

Comment: You need to initialize each array with the values you want. There's no true multi-dimensional array that will be fully allocated with merely a declaration.

Comment: Its because, new Array will set an array of length 0. So `a[0][0]` will have an array, but `a[0][1]` will be `undefined`. If you try to explain what you are trying to achieve, we could recommend something

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545641/javascript-multidimensional-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Javascript, there's no use in instantiating variables in advance, and there is no such thing as compile-time memory allocation because, hey, there's no compile time! But if you *really want* to do it, it's not as trivial as in Java:

```
const length = 7;
const range = new Array(length).fill();
const array = range.map(e => range.map(e => range.map(e => e)));

console.log(JSON.stringify(array)); // -> "[[[null,null,null],[null,null,null],[null,null,null]],[[null,null,null],[null,null,null],[null,null,null]],[[null,null,null],[null,null,null],[null,null,null]]]"
```

The only point in it is that you can be always sure that, as long as you stay in [0, length) boundaries, `array[x][y][z]` for any `x`, `y` and `z` will not throw a TypeError.

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this

```js
const items = [[[]]] // init 3d array

// assign values
items[0][0][0] = 0
items[0][0][1] = 1
items[0][0][2] = 2

// display
for (const i of items) {
  for (const j of i) {
    for (const k of j) {
      console.log('k = ', k)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i mean how to use it like java.  eg: double a = new double[length][length][length];

Answer (score 1):

Similar to rishat's answer, but has different length.

```js
const array1 = Array(2).fill().map(e => Array(4).fill().map(e => Array(3).fill("3").map(e => e)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(array1));
```

Answer (score 0):

I took this approach in my current project:

```js
    const sourceImage = [1,2,3,255,4,5,6,255,7,8,9,255,10,11,12,255 ]; // RGBA - 16
    
    let noAlphaImage = [];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < sourceImage.length; i++)
    {       
        if (i % 4 !== 3)
        {
            noAlphaImage.push(sourceImage[i]); 
        }
    }
    
    console.log(noAlphaImage);
    
    const WIDTH = 2, HEIGHT = 2, PIXEL = 3;
    var destImage = [];
    
    for (var w = 0; w < WIDTH; w++)
    {
        destImage[w] = [];
        for (var h = 0; h < HEIGHT; h++)
        {
            destImage[w][h] = [];
            for (var p = 0; p < PIXEL; p++)
            {
                const destIndex = (w * HEIGHT * PIXEL) + (h * PIXEL) + (p);
                destImage[w][h][p] = noAlphaImage[destIndex];      
            }
        }
    }
    
    console.log(destImage);
```