# How to create and push values into an 3 dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need help with making a 3-dimensional array, my objective is e.g:

Just for graphic illustration :-), see row below

[category: 1[subcategories: 1[subsubcategories: 1,2],2[subsubcategories: 3,4]]

In scenario above the user has selected:

```
category 1
subcategories: 1
subsubcategories: 1,2
subcategories: 2
subsubcategories: 3,4
```

I can then with these values create a string like: 1^1:1,2^2:3,4

Hope anyone understands :)

Comment: What difficulty are you having in making a 3d array?

Comment: Why would you want pure arrays instead of creating objects that represent what you need?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [three-dimensional array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40359659/three-dimensional-array-in-javascript)

Comment: I have nothing against object, I just want to collect the data the correct way :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `objects` instead of `arrays`. When you use string indexes on array elements the `array` gets turned into an `object` and some of the array methods might not work properly afterwards. Why not just use an `object` from the beginning then.

> WARNING !!
>   If you use named indexes, JavaScript will redefine the array to a standard object.
>   After that, some array methods and properties will produce incorrect results.

this is taken from [https://www.w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp).

Here is an example of how to use it:

```js
// Object = {} instead of array = []
var myObject = {};
myObject['category'] = {1: {subcategories: {1:[1,2], 2: [3,4] }} };


// For example
var anotherObject = {};
anotherObject['category'] = {1: {}, 2: {}};
anotherObject['category'][1] = [1,2];
anotherObject['category'][2] = [3,4];

// Edit: example 3
// ---------------
// result from database JSON format
var resultFromDB = {"category": {"1": {"subcategories": {"1": {"subsubcategories": [1,2]}, "2": {"subsubcategories": [3,4] }}}} };


// example of building new object from input
var myNewObject = {};
var type;

// go through the first level 
for(var index in resultFromDB)
{
  // in case you needed this is how you would check type of input
  type = typeof resultFromDB[index];
  if((type === "object") && (type !== null)) // check if its an object
  {
    // set myNewObject[index] to new object
    myNewObject[index] = {};
    // go through second level
    for(var subIndex in resultFromDB[index])
    {
        // set myNewObject[index][subIndex] as new object
        myNewObject[index][subIndex] = {};
        // go through third level
        for(var subSubIndex in resultFromDB[index][subIndex])
        {
           // simply use an '=' to get all from that level
           myNewObject[index][subIndex][subSubIndex] = resultFromDB[index][subIndex][subSubIndex];
           
        }
    }
  }
}


console.log("This is the new object");
console.log(myNewObject);
console.log("\n");
console.log("This is the original object");
console.log(myNewObject);

// If you need to extract in multiple places you could make a function for quick access
function returnObject(incomingObject)
{
    var myNewObject = {};
    var type;
    
    // ... copy paste here all the above code from example 3 except resultFromDB
    
    return myNewObject;
}

// then just call it from anywhere
var theNewestObject = returnObject(resultFromDB);
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwer, could You also give an example on how to add these values with the push method? These values are fetched from a database.

Comment: @ChristerEngholm I will edit with a few examples to show you what you can do.

Comment: Thanks, I can't wait to check them out :)

Comment: @ChristerEngholm Alright, I got it. Check the code for `// Example 3`, that's it. If your incoming results from the database are in `JSON` format (they should be),  this should work for you exactly as it is. Tell me if it works, if not post your incoming (from the db) data so I can see exactly what it looks like and then I can tweak the function.