# Using variables as keys in multidimensional object

Tags: javascript, object, multidimensional-array

If I have some values and I want to store it as an object. So finally I need to call `JSON.stringify()` (because I am trying to store it in chrome extension)

```
var id = '1';
var name = 'Mali Bakery'
var url = 'http://example.com/'
```

So I thought the best thing would be sorting it like:

```
var items = {
     id : {
        'name': name,
        'url': url
     }
}
```

But I couldn't figure out how to put the variables inside the object template.

I tried using

```
item = {}
item[id] = id
item[id].name = name  
// etc

items.push(item);

// and also, this approach too
items.id = id
```

But no success.

Comment: You should look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545641/javascript-multidimensional-array

Comment: Keep in mind that `name` won't work as a variable if it's a global variable. `window.name` will overwrite it.

Answer (score 2):

You can put `id` in brackets `[]` so that it gets evaluated to the variables value:

```js
var id = '1';
var name = 'Mali Bakery'
var url = 'http://example.com/'

var items = {
      [id] : {
        name,
        url
     }
}

console.log(items);
```

Note that you shouldn't use `name` as a variable's name!

Answer (score 2):

You could do this

```
var id = '1';
var name = 'Mali Bakery'
var url = 'http://example.com/'
var items = {}

items[id] = {
    'name': name,
    'url': url
}

console.log(items);
```

This gives the following output:

`{
  1:{
    name: "Mali Bakery",
    url: "http://example.com/"
  }
}`

Answer (score 1):

```
var items = {};
items[id] = { name, url };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    var id = '1';
    var name = 'Mali Bakery'
    var url = 'http://example.com/'

    var obj = {
            'name': name,
            'url': url
         }

    var items = {};

    items[id] = obj;
```