# What is format of object JS?

Tags: javascript

There is an array:

```
var data = data.addRows([
        ['Nitrogen', 0.78],
        ['Oxygen', 0.21],
        ['Other', 0.01]
      ]);
```

What does it mean? Arrays in array? What is it `['Nitrogen', 0.78]` ? Why `[]` brackets?

I tried to reproduce this like:

```
var arr = [];
arr.push({'Oxygen', 0.21});
```

Comment: you should do arr.push(['Oxygen', 0.21]);

Comment: "*What does it mean? Arrays in array?*". It's exactly that - an array with multiple arrays contained within that array (otherwise known as a multidimensional array).

Comment: `{'Oxygen', 0.21}` is a syntax error, as you've discovered. To reproduce it you'd write `arr.push(['Oxygen', 0.21]);`

Comment: [This question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545641/javascript-multidimensional-array) may help.

Comment: I tried push like: `var item = [key, value];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is an array of arrays. Otherwise known as a multidimentional array. The `[]` inside the `[]` backets indicate a seperate arrays.

Pointy has already answered this in the comments but I will put it here.

`arr.push({'Oxygen', 0.21});` is pushing an object to an array, which is denoted by the `{}` curly braces (However if you did want to push an object to an array the syntax would actually be `arr.push({'Oxygen' : 0.21});)`. In order to push an array to array you would need to do `arr.push(['Oxygen', 0.21]);`, which is using `[]` square brackets.

Comment: I know that it is arraya in array, but how to reproduce this `['Nitrogen', 0.78]`?

Comment: Pointy has already shown you in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

yes it's array within an array; if you want to reproduce it should be like the following

```
var arr = [];
arr.push(['oxygen',0.21]);
// to see what's inside 
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));

// to check the type 
for ( var i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++ ){
 console.log('array[',i,'] = ', typeof(arr[i]));
}
```