# Add many javascript array in single javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
UPDATE! ADDING PHP code

 <?php 
   $tq_array = array();
   $c_array = array();
   $o1_array = array();
   $o2_array = array();
   $o3_array = array();
   $questions = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE exam_code = '$exam'");
      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($questions)){
         $tq_array[] = $row['test_question'];
         $c_array[]= $row['correct_answer'];
         $o1_array[] = $row['option_1'];
         $o2_array[] = $row['option_2'];
         $o3_array[] = $row['option_3'];
      }
      $tq_json = json_encode($tq_array);
      $c_json = json_encode($c_array);
      $o1_json = json_encode($o1_array);
      $o2_json = json_encode($o2_array);
      $o3_json = json_encode($o3_array);
 ?>
```

my problem is i want to add this converted javascript array (from php array) to another storage.

```
var questioner = JSON.parse('<?= $tq_json; ?>');
var correct_ans = JSON.parse('<?= $c_json; ?>');
var option1 = JSON.parse('<?= $o1_json; ?>');
var option2 = JSON.parse('<?= $o2_json; ?>');
var option3 = JSON.parse('<?= $o3_json; ?>');
```

this is the storage where i want to add the codes

```
var i = 0
for(i = 0; i <= obj1.length;i++){
    var questions = [
       [ /* this is the one that fix the counting of the questioners*/],

       [[obj1[i], obj2[i],  obj3[i],  obj4[i],  obj5[i]],"false",1],



      ],

   sec=20,
   A;
}
```

i try to loop it using for loop but it didnt work.

i like to to appear it like this ()

```
var questions = [
       [ /* this is the one that fix the questioner */],

       [[obj1[i], obj1[i],  obj1[i],  obj1[i],  obj1[i]],"false",1],
        [[obj2[i], obj2[i],  obj2[i],  obj2[i],  obj2[i]],"false",1],
         [[obj3[i], obj3[i],  obj4[i],  obj3[i],  obj3[i]],"false",1],

            So on ....


      ],

   sec=20,
   A;
```

Thank you!

Comment: In your code samples your variables don't match up and we don't know the content of the php-arrays. This makes it very difficult to see exactly what you mean. Could you update this.

Answer (score 0):

You're building a new array for each iteration through your `obj1` array.  We need to promote the scope of the `questions` array and push to it:

```
var i = 0
var questions = [];
for(i = 0; i <= obj1.length;i++){
    questions.push(
       [[obj1[i], obj2[i],  obj3[i],  obj4[i],  obj5[i]],"false",1],
    );
}
```

Comment: i got a blank result sir.

Comment: You'll need to debug and/or use `console.log(questions)` to view the contents of the questions array

Comment: okay sir ill try my best to debug. ill tell u the result later

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to create a multidimentional array which maybe harder to read, so I'd suggest you use objects instead.

But the answer here should help
[JavaScript multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545641/javascript-multidimensional-array)

Comment: i think im not using multidimentional sir. im using row arrays.