# Strange array.push in JS

Tags: javascript

I have simple code

```
sites_from_session = 12;
function function_name () {
    var items_to_send = sites_from_session;
    var template_name = jQuery('#new-site-template-name').val();
    console.log(sites_from_session);
    items_to_send.push(template_name);
    console.log(sites_from_session);
}


function_name();
function_name();
function_name();
function_name();
function_name();
function_name();//...
```

The problem is that the `push` method pushes value to both arrays

[image]

Where i am wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you show us the code generating this log ? You don't even create an array here.

Comment: You don`t have arrays in your code in first place. `var items_to_send = sites_from_session;` where is second array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays do not self clone in JavaScript. When you say something like

```
arr1 = arr2;
```

where both `arr2` is a valid array, you haven't made an actual copy of `arr2`. All you've done is create a reference pointer to it for `arr1`. So when you make a change like

```
arr1[0] = "some value";
```

you are (in essence) saying the same thing as

```
arr2[0] = "some value";
```

To properly clone a separate copy you need to use this:

```
var items_to_send = sites_from_session.slice();
```

This will return a new array that holds all of the items from the original array.

Answer (score 0):

It is a very common Javascript problem. The arrays are not copied like this:

```
var items_to_send = sites_from_session;
```

It merely copies the reference of the array to a new variable. In other words, `items_to_send` and `sites_from_session` are two names pointing to the same array in RAM. If you want to make a copy of the array (called deep copying) rather than just another pointer (shallow copying), you need to use `slice()`:

```
//create a copy of the array
var items_to_send = sites_from_session.slice(0);
```

The rest of your code should work fine.

Possible duplication of this question: [How do you clone an Array of Objects in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597588/how-do-you-clone-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

You can learn more here: http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-clone-array