# How to return a variable and at the same time reset/delete it

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a validator library, that is sanitizing and validate strings. 
The validator functions are pushing a message to a array "errors" for every nonvalid input they find.

When validation on all input is complete I collect the errors in a variable like this:

```
var errors = validator.getErrors();

// Function definition
Validator.prototype.getErrors = function () {
    return this._errors;
}
```

The var "errors" will now be an array containing 0 to several string elements. Right after this I'm calling a function for emptying the errors in the validator.

```
validator.clearErrors();

// Function definition
Validator.prototype.clearErrors = function () {
  this._errors = [];
}
```

**Question:** Can i somehow re write the getErrors() function so that is also empty it's internal _errors variable?... Then I can remove the clearErrors function altogether.

Comment: When I look at it I really dont know why i have `return this;` in the clearErrors function. This function should not really return anything. Just reset the internal variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not simply this ?

```
Validator.prototype.getErrors = function () {
    var r = this._errors;
    this._errors = []; 
    return r;
}
```

But conventionally, functions named `getXXX` should not have any side effects. Clearing the source in a `getErrors` function is a little surprising. If you want to keep only one function, you might call it something like `popErrors` for example.

Comment: This is so easy when you explain it! Very good that you also give some advice regarding "good coding standards" and naming of functions!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you clone the array of errors and then reset it before returning the cloned array values

[How do you clone an Array of Objects in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597588/how-do-you-clone-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

```
Validator.prototype.getErrors = function () {
    new_array = this._errors.slice(0);
    this._errors = [];
    return new_array;
}
```

Comment: Why clone it ? That seems useless here.

Comment: @dystroy care to explain how? 'var r = this._errors;' will simply pass the reference of one array to another, so when this._errors changes, 'r' changes too

Comment: @gurvinder372 *this._errors = []* does not change the existing array, but creates a new one and points *this._errors* to it. The previous array stays unchanged.