# js output unsorted array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I have the below code which is also in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9banN/).
I have listed the output and the expected output below.  I can't understand why I haven't sorted the rNums yet it still outputs the sorterd results?

If I comment out the sort function then random appears as I want but not ordered.  What am I doing wrong here?

Random should be displaying as it is in nNums and ordered should be displayed in numerical order?

```
    <ul id="random"></ul>
    <ul id="ordered"></ul>

    <script>
    var rNums = [1,5,3,2,4];
    console.log(rNums);
    var sortRNums = rNums;

    sortRNums.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a - b
    });

    $.each(rNums, function (index, value) {
        $("#random").append('<li>' + value + '</li>');
    });

    $.each(sortRNums, function (index, value) {
        $("#ordered").append('<li>' + value + '</li>');
    });
    console.log(sortRNums);
    </script>
```

Output

```
    <ul id="random">
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="ordered">
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
    </ul>
```

Expected Output

```
    <ul id="random">
            <li>1</li>
            <li>5</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>4</li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="ordered">
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sort` modifies original array you need to create a copy before sorting.

```
var sortRNums = rNums.slice(0);
```

Comment: Thanks I thought I must have been close this is now working.  I will have to some more reading on slice

Answer (score 2):

It's is because variable sortNums is pointing to same memory location
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9banN/2/)

```
var rNums = [1,5,3,2,4];
var rUnsortedNums = $.map(rNums, function(i){return i;});
console.log(rNums);
var sortRNums = rNums;

sortRNums.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a - b
});

$.each(rUnsortedNums, function (index, value) {
    $("#random").append('<li>' + value + '</li>');
});

$.each(sortRNums, function (index, value) {
    $("#ordered").append('<li>' + value + '</li>');
});
console.log(sortRNums);
```

Answer (score 2):

The Problem is, that

```
var sortRNums = rNums;
```

does not copy the array. sortRNums and rNums point to the same array.

Just take a look at this thread for more information:
[How do you clone an Array of Objects in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597588/how-do-you-clone-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)