# JQuery Extends on string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, clone, extends

i have to create a custom function that clone objects despite of their types.
IE. an array should be copied as an array, string as string etc.

The result of `clonedObject = jQuery.extend(true, {}, object);` with arrays is an object with numerical indexes, for string is an object of characters with numerical indexes.

There is a better way to make this work than checking the type of the object and writing custom clone functions?

Thanks in advance,
Mattia

Comment: Example please? (JSFiddles are nice) :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie [No need for JSFiddle](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) anymore ;)

Comment: George: Nice.. That's new :) Ooooh extra button! Can a newbie get access to that editor though?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Pretty decent, huh? I think it's available to everybody.

Comment: @Mattiag: Can you try the new Code Snippet feature and add an example directly into your question?

Answer (score 0):

if you just need a shallow copy you can use as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597588/how-do-you-clone-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript/4136943#4136943)

```
var newCopiedArray=old_array.slice(0);
```

Check the code snippets [here](http://jsfiddle.net/70f56r2q/)