# Splice doesn't copy array of objects

Tags: javascript

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Pg4vbR6NREn57HsopS4d?p=preview) I have an example of an array of objects `a` that I copy with `slice()` to `b`.  I alter one of the objects in `a` but it changes also `b`. Isn't `slice` supposed to copy the array, including its contents? I need `a` and `b` to have different pointers.

Javascript

```
var a = [{x1:1, x2:2}, {x1:3, x2:4}];

var b = a.slice();


a[1].x1 = 5;


console.log(b[1]);
```

this prints:

```
x1: 5 
x2: 4
```

Comment: [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) makes a shadow copy, not a deep copy.

Comment: how can I achieve a copy? do I have to do that manually?

Comment: @Raphael the questions are different, in my question I'm asking about slice, in the question you pointed slice is the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MDN:

> For object references (and not the actual object), slice copies object
> references into the new array. Both the original and new array refer
> to the same object. **If a referenced object changes, the changes are
> visible to both the new and original arrays.**
>
> For strings, numbers and
> booleans (not String, Number and Boolean objects), slice copies the
> values into the new array. Changes to the string, number or boolean in
> one array does not affect the other array.

Performing a deep copy on objects in the array is difficult, but [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23481096/) suggests a way to do it, as long as your array only contains JSON-serializable content:

`var clonedArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(originalArray));`

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript?rq=1) has a variety of answers on how to do a "deep clone".  jQuery, Lodash, Underscore, and other libraries have fairly slick methods available.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do Deep copy with jQuery:

```
var b = $.extend(true,{},a);
```

This does a proper deep copy of all your variables.