# Angular 2 Databinding why and how does it work

Tags: angular, data-binding, javascript-databinding

Good Morning from Germany,

first my code works like a charm and I´m happy about the awesome learning curve with Angular 2. I´m getting things faster done than any time before.

My problem is that I dont understand why the databinding works. For what I see, I dont get any piece of code which would it explain. Hope someone can give me a hint.

Basicly I got 3 variables:

```
employee: Employee[]; //For editing a single Employee
employees: Employees[]; //Collects all Employees (Received from PHP)
pagedItems: any[]; //Stores some of the Employees[] to page trough them in ngFor
```

Creation of the list:

```
<ng-template ngFor let-i="index" let-c="count" let-weeks [ngForOf]=" pagedItems">
<div (click)="showDialog($event, people)" *ngFor="let people of weeks; let i2 = index;">
...
```

pagedItems get defined by employees.slice

ShowDialog (=Formular to change a employee):

```
showDialog(event, people) {
    this.employee = people[0];
    //console.log(people[0]);
}
```

My Formular:

```
<p-dialog styleClass="boxSettings" header="Datenerfassung" [(visible)]="displayDatacollect">
    <form-ShiftData *ngIf="employee" [employee]="employee">

    </form-ShiftData>
</p-dialog>
```

In the formular I bind everything to the employee class. On submit I save the data in the database.

So this is basicly everything I do. My problem is now that I dont understand why, If I change the employee class in my formular (even in front of submitting) the class employees and the pagedItems class are changing. And so also my List.

What I see is that I set the variables like: employees -> pagedItems -> people -> employee

But no line which could lead in the other direction. So somehow Angular does this on his own.

If you could explain it or just send a tutorial which explains it, I would be very happy.

EDIT 1:

```
@Input('employee') employee: Employee;
```

This way I import it in the formular component, also not quite sure why I dont write here:

```
@Input('employee') employee: Employee[];
```

But otherwise it wont work.

Ah and If I already ask, If you have a hint how I can set displayDatacollect (Formular) inside of form-ShiftData (Separate Component) I would be happy to :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question, this is not related to Angular but to how object references work in JS.

It is the **same** employee object that is in *employee, employees and pagedItems*.

When you do something like `pagedItems = employees.slide(...)` you get a new array, but this array contains the same object as the employees array.

For example :

```
var tab = [ obj1, obj2, obj3 ];
var slice = tab.slice(0, 1); //slice = [ obj1 ]
// obj1 is the same object as in tab. So if you modify slice[0], you modify tab[0]
```

Edit (after you comment):

If you want to modify the employee without affecting the original array, then you need to modify a copy of the employee. You can do this using `Object.assign`  :

```
var employeeCopy = Object.assign({}, employee)
// now you can modify your employeeCopy without affecting the original object
// note that if employee contains a refernce to another object, employeeCopy and employee will share the same reference
```

If you need to perform a deep copy of an array, then you will have to do it yourself, by creating a copy of each object in the original array.
You can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597588/how-do-you-clone-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: First at all thank you! For real ? So how would I seperate slice from tab ? Lets say I want to let the user change slice but later compare it to obj1 (tab[0]) this wouldn´t be possible.