# Using Javascript slice updates old values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to write a function that picks a random entry from a multidimensional array (myArray), saves it to a new variable (myTempArray) and updates the first entry with an id number (counter).

When I change the value of mytempArray[0][0][0] it updates the equivalent value in myArray as well. I don't want these values to change.

How do I stop this from happening? Is slice the wrong method to use? If so, how do I duplicate the original array entry so I can modify it and use elsewhere? Code is below:

```
var myArray = [
[[0, "Description 1", 0, 0, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0, true, 0]],
[[0, "Description 2", 0, 0, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0, true, 0]],
[[0, "Description 3", 0, 0, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0, true, 0]],
];

function randomNumber (min, max) {
return Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + min);
};

counter = 1;

function myfunction(){

myrand = randomNumber(0,myArray.length-1); 
mytempArray = myArray.slice(myrand,myrand+1);
mytempArray[0][0][0] = counter;
counter++;
};

myfunction();
```

Comment: Arrays are reference types. `slice` only does a shallow clone, the nested arrays are copied over to the new one by reference.

Comment: Take a look here for how to deep copy arrays. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597588/how-do-you-clone-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript

Comment: Other than `Object.assign()` you also can use the `...[]` spread operator.

Comment: @ThirueswaranRajagopalan: Both spread and rest are *syntax*, not operators.

Comment: @ThirueswaranRajagopalan ...and neither one does a deep clone.

Comment: @JaredSmith yes i was aware of it, was giving pointers of some techniques to utilize within a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that `slice` only works at one level in your structure. If you want a *deep* copy, you have to implement that yourself.

```
function myfunction() {
    var myrand = randomNumber(0, myArray.length - 1);
    var mytempArray = myArray.slice(myrand, myrand + 1); // <== Only copies one level
    mytempArray[0] = mytempArray[0].slice();             // <== Copy the next
    mytempArray[0][0] = mytempArray[0][0].slice();       // <== And the next
    mytempArray[0][0][0] = counter;
    // Presumably do something with `mytempArray` or return it
    counter++;
}
```

See below for a couple of other changes I made in there.

---

A couple of side notes:

- Unless you're declaring `myrand` and `mytempArray` somewhere you haven't shown, your code is falling prey to [The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)*. Be sure to declare your variables.
- There's no need for a `;` at the end of a function *declaration* (as opposed to a function *expression*). `;` is a statement terminator. Declarations aren't statements.

---

* *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*

Comment: Assuming that the data is valid JSON, `var deepCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(oldArray));`.

Comment: @JaredSmith: I believe strongly that using `stringify`+`parse` to copy data is wrong on several levels. :-)

Comment: Well, the general-purpose alternative is to recursively copy the data structure. Which in JavaScript means either trampolining or keeping an explicit stack to avoid running out of memory. Or you could write a million one-off versions for specific data structures with all the duplication and bug-potential that implies. I don't think it's going to be 'right' no matter which way you slice it (pun intended).

Comment: thanks @T.J.Crowder that worked!