# javascript - how to clone Array without reference

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to clone Array to a new one, and I want cloned array has no reference to original copy

I know there're `splice` and `from` method, but new array from those methods all has reference to original array

e.g.

```
let original = [ [1,2], [3,4] ];
let cloned = Array.from(original); // this will copy everything from original 
original[0][0] = -1;
console.log(cloned[0][0]); // the cloned array element value changes too
```

I also tried using loop to have `cloned[i][j] = original[i][j]`, but result is the same

How can I create a new Array with every element having same value from original Array, but the cloned Array should have no reference to original Array?

thanks!

Comment: `Array.prototype.slice` copies the array

Answer (score 20, accepted):

By using this method we can create a copy of an array. Please check the below example. Credits to this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597588/how-do-you-clone-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

```js
let original = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4]
];
let cloned = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(original)); // this will copy everything from original 
original[0][0] = -1;
console.log(cloned); // the cloned array element value changes too
console.log(original);
```

```css
.as-console {
  height: 100%;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: awesome! this is exactly what I need!

Comment: @jerry You're welcome!

Comment: This works smoothly!

Comment: this solution worked like a charm, tried to slice method and did not make it work. Thank u.