# Why are these methods disappearing when I clone the array?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

For some strange reason, when this data:

```
// data
visitorsTemplate: [{
  text: '',
  type: 'buttons',
  children: [{
    name: 'email',
    method: (e) => { this.sendEmail(e) }
  }]
}]
```

Is cloned:

```
// watch
console.log(this.visitorsTemplate)
const visitorItem = clone(this.visitorsTemplate)
console.log(visitorItem)
```

With this function:

```
// utils
export const clone = (...args) => {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify.apply(null, args))
}
```

the *method* attribute disappears. Here are the `console.logs`:

```
[{
  text: "",
  type: "buttons",
  children": [{
    name: "email",
    method: f method(e)
  }, {
    name: "delete",
    method: f method(e)
  }]
}]

[{
  text: "",
  type: "buttons",
  children": [{
    name: "email"
  }, {
    name: "delete"
  }]
}]
```

**Update:** I found out JSON.stringify is removing the `methods` but I need to create a new array. So how to avoid removing the methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the JSON Specs [here](https://www.json.org) , you will notice that there is no specification for a JSON to contain methods and it contains only data. When you do `stringify` and then parse, you are taking intermediate step as JSON which is causing this.

For a more detailed account on cloning array of objects, please refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597588/how-do-you-clone-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can implement your own deep clone implmentaion of object. Try this code.

```
    function deepcloneObject(obj) {
    var clone = {};
    for(var i in obj) {
        if(obj[i] != null &&  typeof(obj[i])=="object")
            clone[i] = deepcloneObject(obj[i]);
        else
            clone[i] = obj[i];
    }
    return clone;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the moment you do JSON.stringify, they will try to create a string of your JSON object. when you have method inside, it will try to convert to string also.

So, if you want to have a new instance of object you can use this: http://underscorejs.org/#clone

```
newObject = _.clone(visitor)
```

or if you want to be able to create programatically later, you prepare these:

```
function Visitor(){
    return {
    text: '',
    type: 'buttons',
    children: [Child()]
   }
}

function Child(){
    return  {
       name: 'email',
       method: (e) => { this.sendEmail(e) }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.assign` along with `Array.prototype.map`

```
const clonedArray = array.map(a => Object.assign({}, a));
```