# Clone an array of objects which contains another array of objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

In my TypeScript program, I have an array which looks like the following:

```
array = [
  {
    id,
    ...
    nested: [
      {
        id,
        ..
      },
      {
        id,
        ..
      }
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

I need to create a copy of this array, but all methods I've found online (including [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597588/how-do-you-clone-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript) only seem to work with an array of objects and not the nested kind here (as the nested array is also operated upon). Whilst `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array))` *could* have worked, I have a date property in the object which must be preserved.

What can I do?

EDIT: Not sure why this has been marked as duplicate, but I specifically make reference to the fact that that thread does not work in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `lodash.cloneDeep()`? https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#cloneDeep

Answer (score 1):

If You're allowed to use external libraries, take a look at `_.cloneDeep(value)` in [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#cloneDeep) library. The code should look as follows:

```
// Original array
const originalArray = [
  {
    id,
    ...
    nested: [
      {
        id,
        ..
      },
      {
        id,
        ..
      }
    ]
  },
  ...
];

// Cloned array
const clonedArray = lodash.cloneDeep(originalArray);
```

It should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
function extend( a, b ) {
        for( var key in b ) { 
            if( b.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
                a[key] = b[key];
            }
        }
        return a;
    }

copyarray = extend( {}, copyarray);
extend( copyarray, array);
```