# Revert changes to array in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to have a component which can change some elements in it. In reality, a change will be like swapping the object in a given position. I did some POC and tried to do the reverting method to be able to leave it how it was before.

```
export default {
  name: 'Landing',
  data () {
    return {
      items: [
        {
          id: 1,
          category: 'Something something'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          category: 'Something something'
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.originals = this.items.slice(0);
  },
  methods: {
    change() {
      this.items[0].category = 'Changed';
    },
    revert() {
      // ??
    }
  }
};
```

I've tried a couple of things especially after reading this: https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/#Why-isn%E2%80%99t-the-DOM-updating

```
while (this.snacks.length) {
  this.items.pop();
}

this.originals.slice(0).forEach(o => this.items.push(o));
```

But it doesn't work. If I delete the pushing part, I get an empty list correctly but if I try somehow to push it back, it won't work.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you give a working fiddle I can show you what happened.

Basically, because you are modifying the same array object. `this.originals` refers to the same array as `this.items`

Slice returns a [shallow copy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)  of the object. You should either take a [deep copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597588/how-do-you-clone-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript) or your revert should be the one initializing the object.

`this.items.pop();`
will remove the items from `this.originals` as well.

Comment: You're partially right. `this.items.pop()` does not modify this.originals though but elements inside are the same.

Comment: `this.originals` and `this.items` refer to the same array. Wording were poor. :x

Comment: Thanks a lot for finding this!

Comment: Have encountered this issue multiple times. JS although it doesnt have pointers, arrays and objects work similar to the concept of pointers.