# JS/ReactJS - Assigning a new variable changes the original

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

I have a react app with an array formatted like so:

```
var themes = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Light',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Dark',
  }
];
```

I have a method inside my `React Component` that adds a new item to the theme using overrides:

```
  addTheme = (theme) => {
    const base = themes.find(t => t.name.toLowerCase() === theme.base.toLowerCase());
    var newTheme = base ? base : themes[0];
    console.log(newTheme);
    newTheme.id = themes[themes.length - 1].id + 1;
    newTheme.name = theme.name;
    themes.push(newTheme);
    console.log('themes:', themes);
  };
```

The issue I am getting is that setting the `newTheme` variable to the `base` seems to overwrite the base object in the array.

So if I am adding a theme named `Midnight`, the `Dark` theme gets changed also?

[image: logs]

Comment: `var newTheme = base ? base : themes[0];` newTheme is referring to the original one. So you change newTheme property, it also changes to orignal one. Try this: `var newTheme = Object.assign({}, base ? base : themes[0]);`

Comment: Because it all does with references https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597588/how-do-you-clone-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do a copy of a theme object, because `find` returns a reference to the object.

You have 2 options - **shallow** or **deep** copying the object.

**1. Shallow copy** (using ES6):

```
const newTheme = {...base ? base : themes[0]}
```

**2. Deep copy** (If you do not have function properties) :

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(base ? base : themes[0]))
```

Here's a great discussion about - [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/728360/4312466).

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks all for the quick responses. I'll keep this in mind for the future

Comment: I'm afraid this deep copy trick of you is not valid for an object having function properties.

Comment: Thanks! Added it to the answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

The `find()` array method will not return a copy of your theme, but rather a reference to it, so you're actually altering the original theme.

Answer (score 1):

> Use **Object.assign()**

Array.find() method doesn't return a copy of the value matched but the actual matched object from the object array. You need to make a copy of that returned theme object to create the new theme that you wish to add. `Object.assign({}, obj)` returns a clone of the `obj` object (mind you, not deep cloning though).

```
addTheme = (theme) => {
    const base = themes.find(t => t.name.toLowerCase() === theme.base.toLowerCase());
    var newTheme = base ? Object.assign({},base) : Object.assign({},themes[0]);
    console.log(newTheme);
    newTheme.id = themes[themes.length - 1].id + 1;
    newTheme.name = theme.name;
    themes.push(newTheme);
    console.log('themes:', themes);
};
```

Comment: Object.assign might break in IE. Browser Compatibility here : https://mdn.io/object.assign