# Vuejs Prop keeps changing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Basically I'm doing some sorting on an array which gets its value from a prop, as we know props values wont get changed (or at least that's what I read in docs) but when I do a remove on my array, it effects the prop as well:

```
props: ['allquestions','getskills'],
data() {
  return {
    getskillsnew: this.getskills,
    searchwindow: true,
    allquestionsnew: this.allquestions,
  }
},
methods: {
  filterop(value){
    for (i = this.allquestionsnew.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
      if (this.allquestionsnew[i].lastweek === 0) {
        this.$delete(this.allquestionsnew, i);
      }
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.searchwindow = true;
      }, 1000) 
    }
  }
}
```

so after the for-loop is done and I check my prop (all questions) it has been cut down to 5 as like as `this.allquestionsnew` , but i want is that this splice only takes effect on `this.allquestionsnew` not on the prop!

how can i achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript arrays are passed by reference. From the [Vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow) ..

> Note that objects and arrays in JavaScript are passed by reference, so
> if the prop is an array or object, mutating the object or array itself
> inside the child component **will** affect parent state.

To get around this you'll need to create a [deep clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597588/how-do-you-clone-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript) of your array. For example ..

```
data() {
   return {
      getskillsnew:this.getskills,
      searchwindow:true,
      allquestionsnew: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.allquestions)),
   }

},
```

This will only initialize the `allquestionsnew` array when the component is created. If you need its value to be updated when the prop changes you can do that with a watcher.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good practice. If you have prop - then you should affect on it through the parent. If you want to set some data equal to you prop, then  do it in a lifecycle hook:

```
created() {
    this.allquestionsnew = [...this.allquestions]
}
```

As you can see, here I used array destructuring (ES6). This would be much better than you did.