# What do I need to do to ensure that an object I assign in observable is not affected by updates angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular6, reference-type

```
myObj : [] = [];
tmpObj: [] = [];

ngOnInit() {

    this.myService.getData().subscribe(
         data => {
          this.myObj = data.values;
          this.tmpObj = Object.assign([], this.myObj);
        }
    )

}

updateData(prop, val) {
    this.myObj[prop] = val;
}
```

When I call **updateData** method and update the property of **myObj**, this change affect the **tmpObj**. But I don't want the tmObj object to be affected by these changes. What am I supposed to do for this?

Comment: You need to make a deep copy of the object (array) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597588/how-do-you-clone-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

if is an array you can do:

```
  this.myService.getData().subscribe(
         data => {
          this.myObj = data.values;
          this.tmpObj = data.values.slice();
        }
    )
```

or you can do:

```
this.myService.getData().subscribe(
         data => {
          this.myObj = data.values;
          this.tmpObj = data.values.map(x => Object.assign({}, x))
        }
    )
```