# Why does async-await loop returns its result to origin array?

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch

I am using a function `fetchChain` called with an array of objects, each object includes the url and other parameters to call another function `fetchData` to chain `fetch`-Calls. The async/await loop returns its results to the array I fed it with, like so (simplified):

```
fetchChain(array){
    const loop = async (items) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            await fetchData(items[i])
        }
    }

    return loop(array)
    .then(()=>{ return array })
}
```

I can wait for all promises/results to return like so:

```
fetchChain(prepareAjax)
.then((res)=> console.log(res) )
.then(()=> console.log('done') )
```

So why does the loop returns its results to the array it got fed with? There is no specific return or then which returns the results to the origin and I can't wrap my head around about what happens here.

As requested, the `fetchDacta`-function:

```
fetchData(obj){
    // some parameters get added, like so
    obj.timeout = obj.timeout   || 10000, [...];

    const fetchRetry = async (url, options, n) => {
        try {
            return await fetch(url, options)
                .then((response)=> return response.json());
        } catch(err) {
            if (n === 1) throw err;

            return await sleep(obj.delay)
                .then(()=> fetchRetry(url, options, n - 1));
        }
    };

    return fetchRetry(url, {}, obj.retries);
}
```

Comment: Please post the `fetchData` function. Does it modify the item (object?) that was passed to it?

Comment: You should not need that `loop` function at all. Just write `async fetchChain(items) {
        for (const it of items) {
            await fetchData(it);
        }
       return items;
}`

Comment: Thanks for the shortened alternative. I added the fetchData to my question and yes, some parameters can get added inside fetchData, since I don't want to write all of them inside the config I'm passing to fetchChain or fetchData. (I shortened the fn as much as I could)

Comment: `return loop(array).then(()=>{ return array })` you're returning the array you put in right there - why would you expect to get something else?

Comment: @MatthewHerbst I'm actually getting something else => the promises/results I'm getting from fetchData. I'm expecting the original array to be returned when used like this, which isn't the case.

Comment: You say the code above is simplified. Can you post the actual code?

Comment: That would be a mess, since I moved from AJAX to fetch recently. Now I can't reproduce the behaviour and as expected and mentioned by MatthewHerbst the object I passed through gets returned. It was my mistake it seems, probably I overlooked something. Now I'm just pushing the returned promises into a separate array and returning this array similiar to your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly, but I think you're asking why the `array` argument in function `fetchChain` contains information assigned in `fetchData`.

For this you have to look at the difference of [passing by reference vs passing by value](https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0).
In JavaScript Objects and Arrays are automatically passed by reference to a function; which means `array` points to the same memory as `items`, and when you modify `items` you are modifying `array`.

This is a simple example to illustrate passing by reference

```js
let changeMessage = (o) => o.message = 'world';
let obj = { message: 'hello'};
changeMessage(obj);
console.log(obj.message);
// Output: world
```

You can avoid modifying the array by [cloning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597588/how-do-you-clone-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript) it first

Comment: My problem was, that array contained the results of fetchData and not the objects I used for iteration. I may have overlooked, that I modified the object I passed to fetchData somewhere inside it and then your answer would make sense. Since I can't reproduce the behaviour even when I go back to my first edit, I'm accepting your answer.