# Array Slice() modifying original array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to copy an array to a new variable and then modify the array.

Code:

```js
    var test = [
        { test: "test1", arr: ["1", "2", "3"] },
        { test: "test2", arr: ["4", "5", "6"] }
    ];

    console.log("test before", test);
    console.log("test before", test[1]);
    console.log("test before", test[1].arr);

    var t2 =  [...test] // used .slice(0) but same result
    t2[1].arr = t2[1].arr.slice(0, 1);

    console.log("test after", test[1].arr);
    console.log("t2", t2[1].arr);
```

output:

```
test before:  
0: {test: "test1", arr: Array(3)} //arr: (3) ["1", "2", "3"]
1: {test: "test2", arr: Array(1)} // arr: (1) ["4"]

test before: 
{test: "test2", arr: Array(3)} //arr: (1) "4"

test before: (3) ["4", "5", "6"]

test after: ["4"]

t2: ["4"]
```

As you can see spread operator/ slice() is modifying the original value.
I also tried to use `var t2 = Object.Create(test)` [same result].

Comment: @undefined Yeah, I want to modify t2[1].arr. It had 3 elements first, but I want only the first element in it so doing slice().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign a an Object/Array to a variable it doesnot copy it. I just sets a reference to original Object/Array. You should use `Object.assign` for shallow cloning and `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` for deep cloning
**Note**: arrays are actually objects in javascript

```js
    var test = [
        { test: "test1", arr: ["1", "2", "3"] },
        { test: "test2", arr: ["4", "5", "6"] }
    ];
    
    console.log("test before", test);
    console.log("test before", test[1]);
    console.log("test before", test[1].arr);
    
    var t2 =  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(test)) // used .slice(0) but same result
    t2[1].arr = t2[1].arr.slice(0, 1);
    
    console.log("test after", test[1].arr);
    console.log("t2", t2[1].arr);
```

However this `JSON.parse(JOSN.stringify(obj))` is not much efficient and will give wrong output in some cases.

#### Using jQuery

```
$.extend(true, {}, obj);
```

#### Using lodash

```
_.cloneDeep(value)
```

[here](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#cloneDeep) You can find detail about this

Answer (score 0):

Array spread (or Array.slice()) are only shallow copy of original array, so sub object are still the same.

For more details about deep copy of objects, take a look at: [How do you clone an Array of Objects in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/597726/6171413)