# Passing Array as Props in vue Modal

Tags: arrays, vuejs2, dataflow

I want to pass array from one component to the other in vueJs, which i am able to do with

```
<add-new-admin-modal
 :permissions = "permissions"
</add-new-admin-modal>
```

In my other component which is a modal actually,
I am receiving the props as,

```
props: {
  permissions: {
    type: Array,
    default: () => []
  }
}
```

Here when i try to change the permissions array, it reflects the parent data, As mentioned in the documentation.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow

so i tried with spread operator

```
data () {
 return {
  statePermissions: [...this.permissions]
 }
}
```

The statePermissions array is still empty when i try above method,

I even tried with Object.assign

```
data () {
 return {
  statePermissions: Object.assign([], this.permissions)
 }
}
```

Still it doesn't work.

In my Modal, I am accessing it as

```
<div v-for = "permission in statePermissions" :key = "permission.id">
 ...someHtml here.
</div>
```

The main idea is, I have a component which gets the data through an api, then i have a modal which takes this data and updates it accordingly and submit it to an api.
when the modal is closed, the parent component should need to have the unedited data, so that if modal is reopened it should get unedited data.

In the process of using Modal, My parent component remains in the same state (It neither gets mounted nor changed), so their is no point in making the request for default data again from parent.

Comment: Just to make sure, you do have elements in `permissions`, correct?

Comment: yeah, i have them, that is why parent state is getting updated.

Comment: What would you like to achieve by creating a new state in the child instead of using the parent' data like `v-for="permission in permissions"` ?

Comment: I've updated the question regarding this, pls check.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably that the default value for you prop is an empty array and you're assigning it to a local variable before the property is properly populated by the parent (or it might even be a lifecycle issue).

Try moving your assignment to the local variable to the `mounted()` hook or even better if you wan't it to be reactive `watch` your property:

```
watch: {
  permissions(newValue) {
    this.statePermissions = newValue
  }
}
```

You also don't need to `...spread` an array to assign it to an array.

Answer (score 0):

Since `permissions` is an array of objects, when you make a copy of it, the resulting array is a shallow copy meaning it will contain the same references to objects. That's why modifying the new array's values update the old array's values as well. You need to create copies of the objects inside `permissions`.

If `permissions` only contains primitives, you can do something like this:

`this.statePermissions = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.permissions));`

If `permissions` is of a certain type (i.e. `new Permission()`), you can map it (I think this is cleaner):

`this.statePermissions = this.permissions.map(x => new Permission(x.propA, x.propB, etc.));`

This way, each cloned object in `statePermissions` will have the same properties as the object it's copied from in `permissions`, but it's independent so modifications won't affect the parent it was created from.

[There's a few other ways in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597588/how-do-you-clone-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript).