# When there are two arrays arr1, arr2 and assigning one array to another making one array null doesnt affect other? Any Specific reason

Tags: javascript, arrays

**When there are two arrays arr1, arr2 and assigning one array to another making one array null doesn't affect other? Any Specific reason??Array assignment in JavaScript. consider the below example..**

```js
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0];
        var arr2 = arr1;
        arr1[2]=10;
        console.log(arr1);//[1, 2, 10, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0] 
        console.log(arr2);//[1, 2, 10, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
        arr1 = [];
        console.log(arr1);//[]
        console.log(arr2);//[1, 2, 10, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
```

Comment: `arr2` stores a reference to a created array, as well as `arr1`, this reference is _a value_. Then you set `arr1` to an empty array, but `arr2` still refers to the original array. Objects are created somewhere in the memory, they are not "inside" any variable, variables only hold a reference to the objects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you clone an Array of Objects in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597588/how-do-you-clone-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)