# How can change the clone of an array and not change the original array in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I have a state in my component and i want to clone of this state when click the save button and change and remove some attribute of the clone and then post to back-end , but when i change the clone array the original state change too ; i don't know what to do i trace all of ways to clone array but all of them did not help me ;
below is my codes :

```js
.
.
.
    const [steps , setSteps] = useState([
        {
            id: 1,
            // content: "item 1 content",
            subItems: [
              {
                id: 10,
                isNew : false ,
                hasWorkflow : true ,
                title : 'SubItem 10 content' ,
                approverType : 1,
                approverId : 0 ,
              },
              {
                id: 11,
                isNew : false ,
                hasWorkflow : true ,
                title : 'SubItem 11 content' ,
                approverType : 2,
                approverId : 1 ,
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            // content: "item 2 content",
            subItems: [
              {
                id: 20,
                isNew : false ,
                hasWorkflow : false ,
                title : 'SubItem 20 content' ,
                approverType : 2,
                approverId : 4 ,
              },
              {
                id: 21,
                isNew : false ,
                hasWorkflow : false ,
                title : 'SubItem 21 content' ,
                approverType : 1,
                approverId :  3,
              }
            ]
          }  ,
          {
            id: 3,
            content: "item 3 content",
            subItems: [
              {
                id: 55,
                isNew : false ,
                hasWorkflow : false ,
                title : 'SubItem 20 content' ,
                approverType : 2,
                approverId : 6 ,
              },
              {
                id: 66,
                isNew : false ,
                hasWorkflow : false ,
                title : 'SubItem 21 content' ,
                approverType : 2,
                approverId : 4 ,
              }
            ]
          }
    ]);
.
.
.
.
function handleSaveWorkflow(){
        //const _result = steps.slice(0);
        let _result = [...steps];
        _result.map((item , index) => {
            item.subItems.map((i , ind) => {
                delete i.hasWorkflow;
                if(i.isNew){
                    i.id = null;
                }
                delete i.isNew;
                return i;
            });
            return item;
        });
        const _final = {"steps" : [..._result]};
        console.log('result : : : : : : :: : :: : ' , _final);
        console.log('steps : : : : : : :: : :: : ' , steps);
        // alert(_final);
        workflowAxios.post(`/workflow-templates/${props.id}/workflow-template-steps` , '' , _final)
            .then(response => {
                console.log('response e e e e e e e : ' , response);
                // setSteps(response);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('error r r r r r r r r r : ' , error);
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For deep copy try this

```
  let _result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(steps));
```

or

```
  const newArray = steps.map(step => ({...step}));
```

> spread syntax doesn't give a deep copy

**Deep copy**

A deep copy means actually creating a new array and copying over the values, since whatever happens to it will never affect the origin one.

For more clarification and the better understanding, you can refer [How do you clone an Array in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597588/how-do-you-clone-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for your help I try your first solution It worked Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing and Un-Parsing can be quite a performance hit depending on the situation, One convenient alternate way would be that if you use 'Lodash' in your project you can simply use [cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep) like so:

```
const newArr = _.cloneDeep( steps );
```

This returns a new array, leaving the original one untouched.