# React : Checkbox stuck to true, but state is updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've a value in my state to store a list of cities, a checkbox to select them in a table, and an event listener to add the selected value to the state.

I can toggle the checkbox one time, from false to true. Then, it can't toggle to false. I'm logging the state and it's correctly updated, so I don't understand why my checkbox isn't updated.

For example :

- The "New York" check box isn't checked, so state is `[]`
- I can check it, the state changes to `["New York"]`
- When I uncheck it, the state changes to `[]`, but nothing happens in the checkbox

Here's the code :

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);
```

```
<input type="checkbox" onChange={(e) => handleRowSelect(e, bpf.city_name)} checked={selected.indexOf(bpf.city_name) > -1} />
```

```
const handleRowSelect = (e, city) => {
        let arr = selected;
        const index = arr.indexOf(city)
        if (index === -1) {
            arr.push(city);
        } else {
            arr.splice(index, 1);
        }
        setSelected(arr);
        console.log(arr)
        console.log(selected)
        dispatch({ type: 'SET_SEL_BPF', payload: selected })
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are mutating your state `selected`.

The line `let arr = selected;` does not `deep copy` the `selected` State. `arr` and `selected` actually point to the same object in memory.

This means `selected` is being mutated and not updated with a completely new State (aka mutated) I.E. changing the values of the same object instead of creating a completely new obj with it's new values.

When you mutate your state. React does not update properly and it is a big rule in react to never mutate your state.

Look into making a [deep copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597588/how-do-you-clone-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript) of your state and then mutating that `deep copy` and then setting selected to that new *deep copy* `setSelected(*your deep copy*)`

Edit: Looking at the other answers ***BEWARE*** of creating a copy like `let arr = [...selected]`. This will work if the array is only one level deep. But if you have an array of objects like: `let arr = [{}]` or nested arrays `let arr = [[]]` the objects or arrays inside `{}` won't be deep copies and will be mutated. Causing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is [object immutability](https://danburzo.github.io/react-recipes/recipes/immutability.html) in React. Whenever you set a new state, you need to initialize a new object/array to make React understand that your object/array has been changed.

In your case, you're using `arr.push` and `arr.splice` which maintain the same array for the whole time

The change can be

```
const handleRowSelect = (e, city) => {
        let arr = selected;
        const index = arr.indexOf(city)
        if (index === -1) {
            //create a new array, and add city
            arr = [...arr, city] 
        } else {
            //create a new array with `filter`
            arr = arr.filter((city, index) => index !== arr.length - 1)
        }
        setSelected(arr);
        console.log(arr)
        console.log(selected)
        dispatch({ type: 'SET_SEL_BPF', payload: selected })
    }
```

Or you can try this way with a new array initialisation `let arr = [...selected];`

```
const handleRowSelect = (e, city) => {
        let arr = [...selected]; //create a new array from the existing one
        const index = arr.indexOf(city)
        if (index === -1) {
            arr.push(city);
        } else {
            arr.splice(index, 1);
        }
        setSelected(arr);
        console.log(arr)
        console.log(selected)
        dispatch({ type: 'SET_SEL_BPF', payload: selected })
    }
```