# javascript: var arr=getElementsByClassName gets effected in loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

My goal is to iterate through HTML DOM elements, which are defined by a certain classname. I want to change some of those names and for some reason the element_array.length is linked to getElementsByClassName even in the for loop, when just changing the classname. So the logic fails, as this loop suddenly stops at halve of the intended iterations. For 4 elements, only 2 iterations take place basically, since the iterations change the length of the array due to some weird, deep object linking.

```
  var messages = document.getElementsByClassName("WidgetAction Toggle");
  window.alert(messages.length); // Indicates a length of 4
  for (let i=0; i < messages.length; i++)
  {
    window.alert(messages.length); // tells the length through the iterations
    window.alert(messages[i].innerHTML); // shows the content of the element
    messages[i].className='ToggleTicketMessageVisibility'; // changes the class of the element
  }
  window.alert("done"); // Indicates, that the loop finished
```

The output is as follows:

```
-4
-4
-"text"
-3
-"text"
-"done"
```

That means, that the second section in the for loop actually not only gets checked on each single loop, it also re-runs the "linked" function from before.

Setting it from `var` to `const` will not change the result in any way.

How can I change the parameters, which I used to get the array in the first place, without loosing them as part of the array? The thing is, I cannot simply use a while loop to check if still such an element exists, since I do not want to change the class of all of them later.

Sometimes to get rid of such referencing a simple jsonencode and jsondecode to copy an array is sufficient. But in this situation I need functional objects as array elements.

Is there a simple and clean way to achieve this goal without multiple loops?

Basically, what I want is "simple" in theory:

I want a FIXED list of elements before the loop starts and iterate over it, without anything being able to change the content by deep linked object logic.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597588/how-do-you-clone-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript

Comment: Well, the article did not help a lot, especially since I desperately avoid jquery. But somehow it still helped me to google in a different style, what I needed. It was about a live html list and than I found good documentation explaining the issue. Here is a good article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList

Comment: Please do not add answers to your post. Answers should be posted as such: separate answers on the post. In this case, given it's closed as a duplicate, you can post it on the duplicate target if you'd like.

Comment: I guess, that my answer is not matching the other article enough, so I doubt, that it would really add to the excellent questions there. Shall I still post it there?