# How to change data in array with object which was copied?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, object

I'm beginner in JS

Can you help me with simple question, pls?

e.g. I have array such as:

```
const array = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Ferrari',
    type: 'F40',
    price: '350 000$',
    country: 'Italy'
}];
```

How could I copy this array and make changes in copied array?

For example I need such array as:

```
const copiedArray= [{
        id: 2,
        name: 'Audi',
        type: 'A7',
        price: '100 000$',
        country: 'Germany'
    }];
```

Should I write some functions for this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you clone an array of objects in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597588/how-do-you-clone-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: If I add:

const newArray = array.map(a => Object.assign({}, a));
newArray.name = 'BMW'

console.log(newArray)

I will get:

[
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Ferrari',
      type: 'F40',
      price: '350 000$',
      country: 'Italy'
    },
    name: 'BMW'
  ]

How to change name inside the object not to add another one name parameter?

Answer (score 1):

The new way to do it is the [structuredClone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) function.

```
let copiedArray = structuredCopy(array);
copiedArray[0].name = "new-name";
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can write a helper function and called it wherever you want**

```js
const originalArray = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Ferrari',
  type: 'F40',
  price: '350 000$',
  country: 'Italy'
}];


const newData = {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Audi',
  type: 'A7',
  price: '100 000$',
  country: 'Germany'

}

function updateObjects(originalArray, newData) {
  // Use the map() method to create a new array with updated object data
  const newArray = originalArray.map(obj => Object.assign({}, obj, newData));

  // Return the new array
  return newArray;
}


const newArray = updateObjects(originalArray, newData);

console.log(newArray);

//newArray 
// [ {
//   country: "Germany",
//   id: 2,
//   name: "Audi",
//   price: "100 000$",
//   type: "A7"
// }]
```