# issue with the state being directly updated

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a function called when i am trying to update the date but i am getting an error

```
updateDate(value, id){
      let data = [...this.preauthenticationdata];
      const index = data.findIndex(row => row.id == id)
      data[index].dateInput = value
      this.keyInputDate++
      this.SET_ppreauthenticationdata(data);
    }
```

i a trying to call this on the following

```
@input="updateDate($event, props.row.id)"
```

the issue is i am getting an error

**Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.**

what is wrong i am doing here

i have updated the code above as to what i am doing and why it is throwing me an error

Comment: what is the code for `SET_ppreauthenticationdata`?

Comment: `data` is a shallow copy of `this.preauthenticationdata` and you're directly modifying an object in `data`.

Comment: Dave has the right of it.  To elaborate, object values are copied by reference instead of by value during shallow copies.  `data[index].dateInput = value` is the same as `this.preauthenticationdata[index].dateInput = value`.  You need to [deep copy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Deep_copy) first to avoid the error

Comment: so how do i do the deep copy

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23481096/6225326