Changing one copy of an object changes the other copy as wekk
I am implementing a simple table in angular in which i am applying specific functions to modify that table on basis of different conditions like sorting the data on pressing sort button or adding salutation on based of gender.
The data is static and stored in a typescript object. Given is my data object which  I am using in table:-
let empsArrayImport:Employee[]=[
{name:"mike",salary:100,gender:"M"},
{name:"jason",salary:400,gender:"M"},
{name:"robin",salary:9000,gender:"M"},
{name:"beast",salary:5000,gender:"M"},
{name:"jimmy",salary:3000,gender:"M"},
{name:"morris",salary:2000,gender:"M"}

];

export default empsArrayImport;

this is the angular code in which I am showing table data
            <tr *ngFor="let emp of empsArray">

                <td>{{emp.name}}</td>
                <td>{{emp.salary}}</td>
                <td *ngIf="showGender;">{{emp.gender}}</td>
            </tr>

Now I have added a button that adds salutation on the basis of gender

    <button type="button" (click)="addSalutation()" class="btn btn-success mx-2">Add Salutation</button>

But when I press the salutation button it should undo the salutation addition in data.
Following is the implementation of addSalutation function:

import  empsArrayImport  from '../Emps';

empsArray:Employee[]=[...empsArrayImport];
empsTemp:Employee[]=[...empsArrayImport];

addSalutation(){

  if(this.showSalutation){
    this.showSalutation=false;
    
    this.empsArray=empsArrayImport;
    console.log("Temps array in true:");
    console.log(this.empsTemp);
    
  }
  else{

    this.showSalutation=true;
    this.empsArray=this.empsArray.filter((emp)=>{
    if(emp.gender=="M"){

      emp.name="Mr."+emp.name;
    }
    else{
      emp.name="Ms."+emp.name;
    }
    return emp;


  });

   console.log("Temps array in false:");
   console.log(this.empsTemp);
  }

I am using two copies of data so that when press button again i can copy the data from one copy to another to undo the changes.
But somehow changing the empsArray also changes the empsTemp. I cannot understand why this is happening.
Output of console.log() in function:

I want that no changes happen in empsTemp and i can reverse the changes.

Spreading the array is a shallow copy. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/597588/3001761

Turns out I was creating a shallow copy of the object instead of the deep copy that's why I was getting that behavior.
I replaced :
empsArray:Employee[]=[...empsArrayImport];
empsTemp:Employee[]=[...empsArrayImport];

with:
empsArray:Employee[]=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(empsArrayImport));
empsTemp:Employee[]=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(empsArrayImport));

and it solved my problem.

For a modern approach (baseline 2022) to handle deep copying, feel free to use: structuredClone()
empsArray: Employee[] = structuredClone(empsArrayImport);
empsTemp: Employee[] = structuredClone(empsArrayImport);

Performance:
structuredClone() is faster due to its internal algorithm.
Safety:
structuredClone() handles all data types (except Symbol), unlike JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...)) which cannot handle functions, undefined, Date objects, Map, Set, Infinity, NaN, BigInt, RegExp, circular references, etc.
Here’s an example of cloning an object containing a Date type:
const t = { d: new Date() };
console.log(t); // { d: Tue Jul 30 2024 11:04:55 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale) }

const tt = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(t));
console.log(tt); // { d: '2024-07-30T09:04:55.599Z' }

const ttt = structuredClone(t);
console.log(ttt); // { d: Tue Jul 30 2024 11:04:55 GMT+0200 (heure d’été d’Europe centrale) }

You can see the full compatibility table here:
structuredClone() Browser Compatibility

NOTE:
You can use directly
export const empsArrayImport:Employee[]=[
   {name:"mike",salary:100,gender:"M"},
   {name:"jason",salary:400,gender:"M"},
   ...
]

NOTE2: I feel should be (instead use filter)
  this.empsArray=[...empsArrayImport].map((emp)=>(
     {...emp,
      name:emp.gender=="M"?"Mr."+emp.name:"Ms."+emp.name
     }))

